# Rabbit MQ. HA in kubernetes

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there any official documentation about how to deploy RabbitMQ on Kuberentes with HA?

I have found several kubernetes Helm Charts for this but they do not look official.

I'm looking for official and supported way to have HA in kubernetes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the [RabbitMQ Peer Discovery Kubernetes plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s) is a good place for you to start. Notice that there are links to further documentation.